# X configuration location on systems that configure X on the fly at startup

Tags: xorg, configuration

Having not had to muck about with the X configuration in quite a while I've recently found that many Linux current distros no longer use an `xorg.conf` file (unless it is manually created for whatever reason) instead configuring X on the fly at boot. So where is this configuration stored now such that it can be perused? Somewhere in memory, I imagine.

Comment: `Xorg.0.log`...

Comment: I don't think it stores the information anywhere. I think it configures X "on the fly" every time.

Comment: You can explicity run `X -configure >myconf` to create the configuration file.

Comment: @meuh Yes, that's the right answer.

Comment: @Gilles Actually, that isn't the right answer to my question. I don't mean to be rude but my question isn't how to create a file. I'm asking where the auto-generated configuration is maintained. @jasonwryan provided the more accurate answer, although, on my CentOS 7 installation the configuration is stored in `Xorg.1.log` with `Xorg.0.log` keeping track of all activity.

Comment: @jasonwryan Put your comment in an answer and I'll select it.

Comment: @theillien It's maintained in memory, and not easily dumpable. Most if not all the information is available in the log file, but not in a usable form. Also, the difference between `Xorg.0.log` and `Xorg.1.log` is not the kind of information they contain: they are just log files from different instances of the X server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xorg logs to `/var/log/Xorg.n.log` where `n` is the server log file for display `n`. In newer implementations<sup>1</sup>, the log file may be found at `$HOME/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.n.log`.

The log will contain all of the currently loaded values for the running display, including any configuration options loaded through conf files in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`.

---

<sub>1. From Xorg 1.16, X can be run rootless via systemd-logind.</sub>